# R: missing in action with dates/factors

Tags: r

I'm  bit lost in all those formatting and can't make my age function works, I'm not sure where format option applied to source or destination, my goal is to attach AGE column, dx$BIRTH_DATE define exactly like in my source data, factor in this format I can not change it.  I don't want to use lubridate for now, as i need to migrate it to diff env. is it possible.
Thanks much for ur help!!
Mario

```
age_years <- function(from, to) 
{ 
  lt <- as.POSIXlt(c(from, to)) 
  age <- lt$year[2] - lt$year[1] 
  mons <- lt$mon + lt$mday/50 
  if(mons[2] < mons[1]) age <- age -1 
  age 
} 

today <- Sys.Date() #,format="%m/%d/%Y")
class(today)
age_years("1988-06-30", "2003-07-12")
age_years("1988-06-30", date)   ### doesn't work  ???

as.character(dx$BIRTH_DATE)
as.Date(dx$BIRTH_DATE)

dx <- data.frame(ID = factor(c(1,2,3)), BIRTH_DATE = c("1/11/1953","2/12/1977","3/13/2000"), FEM = (c(11,22,33)))
dx
str(dx)

### <@>><
dx$AGE <- age_years(as.Date(dx$BIRTH_DATE), today)   ## Age=1 ?????
```

Comment: `date` is a function, try with `date()`

Comment: Did you check the output of `as.Date(dx$BIRTH_DATE)`? The date is not what you are expecting `"0001-11-19"`. That's November 19, 1 A.D.

Comment: `age_years(as.Date("1988-06-30"), as.Date(today))` gives 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code here is a solution for you. You had 2 major problems, first your BirthDate format was not being declared (as noted by Pierre) second you were calling only the second and first year to declare the age, rather than using the entire dataframe. Now from and to are turned into vectors to define ages. Hope this helps!

```
 age_years <- function(from, to) 
{ 
  from <- as.POSIXlt(from) 
  to<- as.POSIXlt(to)
  age <- to$year - from$year
  mons <- from$mon + from$mday/50 
  if(mons[2] < mons[1]) age <- age -1 
  age 
} 

today <- Sys.Date() #,format="%m/%d/%Y")

dx <- data.frame(ID = factor(c(1,2,3)), BIRTH_DATE = c("1/11/1953","2/12/1977","3/13/2000"), FEM = (c(11,22,33)))

dx$AGE <- age_years(from=as.Date(dx$BIRTH_DATE,format = "%m/%d/%Y"), to=today) 

> dx
  ID BIRTH_DATE FEM AGE
1  1  1/11/1953  11  62
2  2  2/12/1977  22  38
3  3  3/13/2000  33  15
```

Comment: Tx all, and HD Badger, this code still doesn't work, it give me Age=24 for all 3 rows, where this 24 comes from ???,  Alexey sorry, I didn't get your solution,  I need to make dx$AGE works to produce those 3 ages:  62,38,15

Comment: Sorry HDB, it doesn't work in my env at all.  I have error about that lt which comes from my prev defined fucntion??? Error in age_years(from = as.Date(dx$BIRTH_DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),  : 
  object 'lt' not found

Comment: What is that lt ????  @ Pierre Lafortune  this works OK for converting to good format , but plugging it into function still doesn't work for me, somehow I have that lt.  how to clean it, the only place I see it in old my fucntion, even renaming HDB function still doesn't work.  I need to call Microsoft !

Comment: Terribly sorry, I had an issue in my code I left the lt in, hopefully that helps.

The lt was a remnant from your code.

Comment: Any lucky here Mario?

Comment: @HDB:  after taking coffee and moving into brand new machine, you code worked OK, Tx much !  And I tested my function and it's wrong, it alwayse produce 24(!), even it work OK with single argument but for data.frame. Very weird, do you see what is the diff between yours and my function? Tx again.M

Comment: The difference is where you define the object `lt`. When you define that you are telling it to only use `lt$year[2] and lt$year[1]`, in this way no matter how many values you put in you will get the value of `lt$year[2] - lt$year[1]`, in your case 24. I created separate from and to objects which allow for a vector of "from's" and a vector of "to's" (In this case only 1 to). This way you subtract each of your from dates iteratively from the to date.